# Is it possible to partition a new MacBook Pro (November 2023, 16 inch) for windows?

Tags: windows, partition, apple-silicon

I understand that I cannot use Bootcamp since the laptop is running on Apple Silicon.

However I would like to avoid using a virtual machine or emulator.

Is it possible to use disk utility to set up a partition manually? Or am I snookered by the fact that there is no Intel chip in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not today.

> Boot Camp requires a [Mac with an Intel processor](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT211814).

You can partition the Apple Silicon Mac disk and boot other non Microsoft Windows OS, but Boot Camp process won’t work or help you out for any version of Windows in 2023. Specifically, boot camp helps slipline the drivers needed to make Windows optimize and support Apple specific hardware on an Intel Mac. There are no drivers for Apple Silicon hardware so you need to virtualize your OS choice on your hardware choice.

Source is https://support.apple.com/en-us/102622

At work we’re using VMWare Horizon and it’s very slick including web browser support, but the license costs and remote hardware will be prohibitively expensive for a small group or single person in almost all situations.

Here is Microsoft’s recommendation: Azure / Cloud or Parallels Desktop version 18 running Arm versions of Windows 11 Pro and Windows 11 Enterprise.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/options-for-using-windows-11-with-mac-computers-with-apple-m1-and-m2-chips-cd15fd62-9b34-4b78-b0bc-121baa3c568c

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. I guess I basically want an answer to the following: Is it possible for me to manually partition my disk and boot Windows on it, without the help of Bootcamp? In other words, is my only option to use a virtual machine or cloud?

Comment: No. Windows will not run on your Mac @yerman doesn’t matter if you devote the entire drive or partition the drive. It won’t run. You need virtualization. I hope my edit helps you and others

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at Crossover. I've used versions of it previously and it worked quite well.

I've used the shareware version Winery (available from Homebrew as well as its website. Though this works in a different way to Crossover.

The engine behind all this is called WINE (Wine Is Not an Emulator), but this doesn't run on Apple silicon and it appears that there is no one looking to make this work for now. However, Crossover and Winery are options that may help.

And on Apple Silicon, speed seems to be quite good too - though as always depends upon exactly what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

My first reply, be gentle.

I have the MacBook Pro 14" 2023 and went a different route that I'd like to mention.

I essentially did as bmike recommends using Parallels but boot Windows from an external USBC drive. There are multiple tutorials available via web search, e.g. [Installing Windows on External SSD on a Mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOQak0j8SaI). Doing this allows me to have a Windows SSD that I clone for those inevitable oopses.

I use it to run Crestron and other A/V windows only software at a very acceptable speed. Can't game at all but business apps work well.

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial which helped you? This would make your answer more useful for future visitors.

Comment: I'm going to have to go digging for the exact site I used but [Installing Windows on External SSD on a Mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOQak0j8SaI) has all the steps.